# I want to build a csv file uploader using html

Tags: html, css

I want to build an html page that let the user to upload a csv file using a file uploader and submit button
to send the csv file and analyze it further

```
app.py:
@app.route('/mainFunc1', methods=['POST'])
def mainFunc1():
      if request.method == 'POST':
         file = request.files['file1']
         colBody= request.form["file2"]
         colTitle = request.form['file3']
         npt= request.form['inp']
```

I need to get a csv file via input and analyze it further

```
mainFunc.html:
    <form method="POST" action="{{url_for('mainFunc1')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="text-       align:center;">
        <h4>Выбери файл который хочешь анализировать: <input id="file1" type="file" name="file1"     multiple> Важно что-бы это был csv файл.</h4>

        <h4>Что хотите искать?: <input id="inp"  name="inp" multiple> Например: (first review, или most important review) </h4>
        <h4>Столбец с текстом: <input id="file2"  name="file2" multiple>  Важно что-бы это был столбец который есть в csv файле.</h4>
        <h4>Столбец с темой: <input id="file3"  name="file3" multiple>  Важно что-бы это был столбец который есть в csv файле.</h4>

         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg px-4 me-sm-3"><font style="vertical-  align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Запустить</font></font></button>

    </form>
```

I need to get a csv file via input and analyze it further

Answer (score 0):

```
app.py:
@app.route('/mainFunc1', methods=['POST'])
def mainFunc1():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file1']
        colBody= request.form["file2"]
        colTitle = request.form['file3']
        npt= request.form['inp']

mainFunc.html:
<form method="POST" action="{{url_for('mainFunc1')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="text-align:center;">
    <h4>Выбери файл который хочешь анализировать: <input id="file1" type="file" name="file1" multiple> Важно что-бы это был csv файл.</h4>

    <h4>Что хотите искать?: <input id="inp"  name="inp" multiple> Например: (first review, или most important review) </h4>
    <h4>Столбец с текстом: <input id="file2"  name="file2" multiple>  Важно что-бы это был столбец который есть в csv файле.</h4>
    <h4>Столбец с темой: <input id="file3"  name="file3" multiple>  Важно что-бы это был столбец который есть в csv файле.</h4>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg px-4 me-sm-3"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Запустить</font></font></button>

</form>
```

Comment: In order to find out which part of the code you have updated or solved, please add some description